# Editing a post doesn't use the latest revision on Android app

Tags: bug, edits, android-app

I was attempting to edit [an answer I submitted earlier](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121175/how-does-sms-spoofing-work-practically/121297#121297) and I ran into what may be a bug. I had already accepted someone else's edit, using the "Improved edit" button to add some further clarification on top of their edit.

[image: latest revision]

Two days later, someone commented on a grammar mistake, so I went to edit the answer on my phone using the app really quick. To my surprise, when I hit edit I didn't see the last sentence of my answer which I had added in my last edit.

[image: suggest edit showing not the latest revision]

Comment: Repro'd on v1.0.85. After doing [an experiment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904482/), I found out that using "Improve edit" will prevent the app from using the latter edit as the base for further editing. I think the app is confused with revision history *with same time* and chooses the former revision. [Nothing happened with "Reject and edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904339/), since it only added 1 revision.

Comment: Ok, so its not just me then.  Is there somewhere else I should submit a bug report?

Comment: Meta SE is the correct place. In fact, this is already a valid bug report.